# Making pieces of text Stylable (e.g. for urls)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

It's possible in plain HTML to wrap pieces of text in spans or tags that can make it easy to style them later. For example, if I wrap "part can be styled" in a span wit class `stylable`, I could define my own style later for it.

```
This <span class="stylable">part can be styled</span> later if needed
```

I'm new to actionscript, and I'm wondering if something similar exists for actionscript/flex?

I actually need it specifically for urls, but in general too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually possible to do a similar formatting in AS3 , read the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS8d7bb3e8da6fb92f-20050207122bd5f80cb-7ff5.html) about Applying CSS to a TextField.